# Website Speed With Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, optimization, heroku

so I've been working on a website with Heroku. The site is called [Staple Sounds](http://www.staplesounds.com). It's a music website that's built using Ruby on Rails with the SoundCloud API.

I've used a lot of AJAX to improve user's website use when browsing for music. The problem I'm having now, is the website is terribly slow.

I'm pretty new to web design and have no way to know how to go about optimizing the site.

I've done some research and found that the sits TTFB is EXTREAMLY long. 
Here's an image

[image: Chrome Developer Tool].

I'm thinking about paying for a [Heroku DOM](https://www.heroku.com/pricing). I was thinking about getting the hobby level one. Will this improve my sites performance significantly?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Step 1 would be to find out why the response is so slow - it could be anything from slow db queries to excessive API queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without analysing the actual code of your app, here is how I would go about it.

1. Use unicorn or phusion passenger as the app server.
2. Move out all the assets to a cloud service/cdn with the help of fog gem.
3. Do as less processing at runtime.
4. Use curb gem for API calls.
5. Once these are done, use newrelic to find out the what else and fix them one by one.

Also have a look at https://github.com/ankane/shorts/blob/master/Rails-on-Heroku.md which details Instacart's Heroku learnings.

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Awesome, I'll look into these!

Comment: For anyone interested. On my index page, I was running the SoundCloud /resolve method on each post as they looped through the index. This caused the site to slow down A LOT. I moved the /resolve method into my form so the track info is resolved and added into the database instead.

Comment: Awesome! Did newrelic help you figure that? Or did you look into the logs?

Comment: newrelic was a huge help! Thank you for that suggestion, will be using it with all my future projects!